# Only hide scrollbar, not disable scrollbar on Firefox Windows

Tags: css, windows, firefox

**This question is only about Firefox on Windows.**

Here is the spec : The scrollbar should be hidden but scroll should be enabled.

On MacOS, the scrollbars will auto-hide and it is less jarring experience. However on Windows, the scroll bars just stay there and don't auto-hide. On Windows 10, the scrollbars are just too ugly and square.

---

Here are invalid answers or additional limitations:

- Do not add margin/padding to the right/bottom as there is no good prediction of this value.
- Do not use `{overflow:hidden}` as it would disable scrolling.

---

Here is as a CSS class that can be applied on all div/element that will have this behavior. These rules don't work as of now and the ugly scrollbar remains.

How would you fix this CSS class ??

```
.disable-scrollbars {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Newer Firefox and not confirmed */
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; /* Older Firefox*/
}
```

---

The experience should be similar to Chrome/Safari with `-webkit-scrollbar:none;` which works on both MacOS and Windows.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question here. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: The CSS rules I posted doesn't work on Windows. I can add screenshot, but I guess the problem is well known. Folks keep suggesting "nicescroll.js" in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be solved only using CSS. The issue open against Firefox is under discussion for more than 6 years.

Here are the details : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790#c188

There is no solution to this problem until Firefox Devs allow scrollbar customization through what is termed as "CSS Scrollbar Modules".

Until then, Firefox on Windows will have ugly-thick-visible-grey scrollbars.

Comment: A recent update is here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1745850